# Print out an error when a decimal is entered in an int

Tags: java, int, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a program called Revenue, I've satisfied all of the requirements except for one.

```
  System.out.print("\t Enter quantity(ies): ");
    quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (quantity < 0 || quantity > 150 || quantity == '.'){

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t Invalid item price.");
        System.out.println("\t Please run the program again");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thank you for using \"Temple\" store");
        System.exit(0);
```

We have to ask the user for the quantity of the item they're purchasing and it cannot have a decimal or '.' in it. For example, when the user is asked to input the amount of of items they want to purchase, they will enter the number. If they enter a number with a decimal, it should print out

```
     Invalid item price.
     Please run the program again

Thank you for using "Temple" store
```

Comment: Your professor will be disappoint with this

Comment: @getlost I think Kacey wanted to do a `.contains('.')`, but it wouldn't work anyways since his input is an `int` and not a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

`keyboard.nextInt()` will not allow decimals. If you type something like "3.14.15" it will throw an exception. For your error handling, you need to catch this exception and print out a better error message than the stack trace which you see by default.

Comment: @Kacey Can you edit your original question with the details? In particular, what do you mean by "If I type a double"? Also, what error do you get?

Comment: @Kacey Sorry, my guess at the behavior for `Scanner.nextInt()` was incorrect. I have edited my answer with a suggestion of how to fix the problem.

Comment: Use a `try-catch`. Catch that exception and ask the user to try again.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage It looks like the OP should just print out an error message like "Please run the program again".

Comment: Why not just have the `Scanner` in the `catch` as well? That way the user doesn't have to run the program again.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage What happens if the user inputs *another* invalid value? Seems like a loop would be ideal here. I'm assuming that the OP is a beginner and probably hasn't learned about loops yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the try-catch block to accomplish what you want:

```
  System.out.print("\t Enter quantity(ies): ");
  try{
    quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (quantity < 0 || quantity > 150)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("\t Invalid item price.");
     System.out.println("\t Please run the program again");
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Thank you for using \"Temple\" store");
     System.exit(-1); //-1 signs an error to the application that launched the program
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
  String quantity = keyboard.next();  // use keyboard.next() instead of keyboard.nextInt() 
                 // because it will throw Exception if value is other 
                                       //than int   

   boolean flag = quantity.matches("[0-9]+");
    if (flag) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(quantity) < 0
                || Integer.parseInt(quantity) > 150) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    if (!flag) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t Invalid item price.");
        System.out.println("\t Please run the program again");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thank you for using \"Temple\" store");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: What happens if the user types "abcde"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : Thanks I missed to check String

Comment: What about "!@#$%"? We could keep going. I think a simpler solution is to still call `nextInt()` which will take care of many error cases (including ones we don't think about) and catch the thrown exception on bad input.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : I think this will filter only digit

Comment: Yes, that looks good. Note that you are basically rewriting the logic of `Scanner.nextInt()` and `Integer.parseInt()`.